# Making a void toBST function in C which takes 2 arguments : Tree* root and an array and adds all tree nodes to an array - order does not matter

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to implement the following function in C :

```
void BSTtoArr(Tree * root,Tree* arr[])
```

which takes a tree and add its nodes into an array of nodes.
What I ve written so far was :

```
void BSTtoArr(Tree * root,Tree* arr[]) {
    static int pos = 0;
    if(root == NULL) return;
    BSTtoArr(root->left,arr);
    v[pos++] = root->data;
    BSTtoArr(root->right,arr);
}
```

I also tried

```
void BSTtoArr(Tree * root,Tree* arr[],int i) {
    if(root == NULL) return;
    BSTtoArr(root->left,arr,i+1);
    v[i] = root->data;
    BSTtoArr(root->right,arr,i+1);

}
```

However I can not get the values added , when I am trying to call the function

```
Tree* arr = (Tree*) malloc(TreeSize(root) * sizeof(Tree));
BSTtoArray(root,&arr);
```

The values are not added properly.
Can you help me with an implementation for this function?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is `storeBST`? Did you mean to call `BSTtoArr` recursively instead? Also, what is `v`?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must provide complete code. Please provide a complete [mre]. Include the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: You allocate memory for `Tree` elements but your function signature expects an array of pointers.

Comment: Is `storeBST` supposed to to be `BSTtoArr` ?

Comment: Yes , its the same function

Comment: `BSTtoArr(root->left,arr,i+1);` stores a complte subtree. Yet the caller assumes that only one array element will be populated. `BSTtoArr(root->right,arr,i+1);` will store the other subtree in exactly the same array positions.

Comment: Your function relies on the fact that `pos` is static and is updated in recursive function calls. That also means that you can only use that function once.

Comment: Also: why don't you use the functions *return value* to communicate the number of filled array elements to the caller?

Comment: Side note: What you need that function for (gfg was linked from [this (duplicate?) question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69826535/1312382), order actually *does* matter!

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is here:

```
Tree* arr = (Tree*) malloc(TreeSize(root) * sizeof(Tree));
```

This gives you "an array" of `Tree` elements but what you want is "an array" of **pointers** to `Tree` elements.

So change it to:

```
Tree** arr = malloc(TreeSize(root) * sizeof *arr);
```

The second problem is here:

```
void BSTtoArr(Tree * root,Tree* arr[],int i) {
    if(root == NULL) return;
    BSTtoArr(root->left,arr,i+1);  <---- i+1
    v[i] = root->data;             <---- data ???
    BSTtoArr(root->right,arr,i+1); <---- i+1

}
```

You pass the same array index to the left and the right recursion so the recursive calls will write to the same index. You need to make sure that every time you write to the array, it's done with a new index value. To do that you can pass a pointer to the index variable and update the index when a new element is inserted in the array.

Further, you to try to save `root->data` into the array but the array is supposed to hold the nodes - not the node data.

To solve this you can do:

```
void BSTtoArr(Tree * root, Tree* arr[], int* i) {
    if(root == NULL) return;
    BSTtoArr(root->left, arr, i);
    v[*i] = root;
    *i = *i + 1;
    BSTtoArr(root->right, arr, i);

}
```

and call it like:

```
Tree** arr = malloc(TreeSize(root) * sizeof *arr);
int i = 0;
BSTtoArray(root, arr, &i);
```