# How would you write this code in C using arrays instead

Tags: c

```
void storeBSTNodes(Node* root, vector<Node*> &nodes)
{
  if (root == NULL)
    return;

  storeBSTNodes(root->left, nodes);
  nodes.push_back(root);
  storeBSTNodes(root->right, nodes);
}
```

How would you write this code in C (it's in C++ format currently) using an array? This is what I've got so far, but I'm confused about the part regarding `nodes.push_back(root);` and `root->left, nodes`

```
void storeBSTNodes(Node* root, int arr[])
{
  if (root == NULL)
    return;

  storeBSTNodes(root->left, arr);
  ?
  storeBSTNodes(root->right, arr);
}
```

Code from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-normal-bst-balanced-bst/

Comment: Google for `realloc`

Comment: Same quistion as https://stackoverflow.com/q/69822932/4386427 ???

Comment: @4386427 the wonders of school assignments shortly after the semester's start

Comment: `int arr[]` would have to be changed since you would need to know the number of elements in the array, you would need to return the new number of elements in the array, and you would need to return the updated pointer. It might help to use a vector-like "class"/module.

Comment: `int arr[]` is wrong as you want to store `Node*` in the array

Comment: That link provides once more the poor quality of gfg... `newNode` function instead of a constructor in C++ – only can shake heads about.

Comment: I would probably use a new structure type to hold the length of the vector and a pointer to the dynamically allocated storage: `struct Node_vector { size_t length; Node **vector; };`, have some way to initialize it (the "universal" initializer `= { 0 };` will do), and write functions to manipulate the vector.

Comment: Why do you need to implement the BST using recursion? Is storing a parent node pointer an option? It would speed up the program immensely, while at the same time making it safer and less memory consuming.

Answer (score 1):

The key is `realloc`.

But you'll soon realize that `Node arr[]` would have to be changed since you would need to know the existing number of elements in the array, and you would need to return the new number of elements in the array and the updated buffer pointer. Using a vector-like "class" or library would help.

Given the (untested) library below, you could use the following:

```
void storeBSTNodes(Node* root, Vector* nodes)
{
  if (root == NULL)
    return;

  storeBSTNodes(root->left, nodes);
  Vector_push(nodes, root);             // Ignores failures.
  storeBSTNodes(root->right, nodes);
}
```

`Vector.h`:

```c
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

#include <stdlib.h>

// A fixed-size circular buffer.
typedef struct {
   size_t size;
   size_t used;
   void** buf;
} Vector;

// Returns NULL and sets errno on error.
// Free the vector with Vector_delete when done.
Vector* Vector_new(void);

// Returns 0 and sets errno on error.
// Destroy the vector with Vector_destroy when done.
int Vector_init(Vector* v);

// Inverse of Vector_new.
// Only call when the vector is empty.
void Vector_delete(Vector* v);

// Inverse of Vector_init.
// Only call when the vector is empty.
void Vector_destroy(Vector* v);

int Vector_is_empty(Vector* v);

// Appends an element to the vector.
// Returns 0 and sets errno on error.
int Vector_push(Vector* v, void* ele);

// Removes the last element of the vector and returns it.
// Note that this also NULL if empty.
void* Vector_pop(Vector* v);

#endif
```

`Vector.c`:

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "Vector.h"

Vector* Vector_new(void) {
   Vector v = malloc(sizeof(Vector));
   if (v == NULL)
      goto Error1;

   if (!Vector_init(v))
      goto Error2;

   return v;

Error2:
   free(v);
Error1:
   return NULL;
}

int Vector_init(Vector* v) {
   v->size = 0;
   v->used = 0;
   v->buf = NULL;
   return 1;
}

void Vector_delete(Vector* v) {
   Vector_destroy(v);
   free(v);
}

void Vector_destroy(Vector* v) {
   assert(v->used == 0);
   free(v->buf);
}

int Vector_is_empty(Vector* v) {
   return v->used == 0;
}

int Vector_push(Vector* v, void* ele) {
   if (v->used == v->size) {
      size_t new_size = v->size;
      new_size = new_size ? new_size * 2 : 4;

      void* new_buf = realloc(v->buf, new_size * sizeof(void*));
      if (new_buf == NULL)
         return 0;

      v->size = new_size;
      v->buf  = new_buf;
   }

   v->buf[ (v->used)++ ] = ele;
   return 1;   
}

void* Vector_pop(Vector* v) {
   if (v->used == 0)
      return NULL;

   return v->buf[ --(v->used) ];
}
```

Add other "methods" as needed.

Comment: `Vector_push` looks a bit dodgy....

Comment: `size_t new_buf = v->size;` and `new_size = new_size ? 4 : new_size * 1.2;` are wrong.

Comment: Also, the return type of `Vector_pop` is wrong.

Comment: I think you meant `new_size = new_size ? new_size * 1.2 : 4;` (although personally, I'd try and avoid the floating point stuff).

Comment: Also 4 * 1.2 is still 4. :-) (But I see you just fixed that now.)

Comment: Sorry for problems, thought I'd have time to test (and still planned on doing it later). Focused on making sure the key idea was illustrated.

Comment: No problem. I added back the `: 4`  that went AWOL in your previous edit since you're in a rush!

Comment: This will be horribly, horriby inefficient. It's very bad to use recursion. It's extremely bad to use non-tail recursion. Repeated realloc calls upon that...

Comment: Aside: This `Vector_push` should probably be called `Vector_push_back`.

Comment: @Lundin That's all true, but the question wasn't how to make it more efficient. :-) (Besides, you'd need either the total number of elements or a parent pointer in order to avoid recursion.)

Comment: @IanAbbott Aye so the first question one should ask when giving this task is: may I know the total number of elements/depth or use a parent pointer. Rather than: "hey what if we do some realloc as well"...

Comment: Re "*This `Vector_push` should probably be called `Vector_push_back`.*", Why? Push is the name of the operation.

Comment: @Lundin, Re "*It's very bad to use recursion. It's extremely bad to use non-tail recursion.*", huh? I didn't use any recursion. You mean the OP's code? Wrong node! /// Re "*Repeated realloc calls upon that...*", yeah, no way to avoid that. But it was done smartly. `Vector_push` is amortized O(1) (O(N) to use N times).

Comment: @ikegami Oh yes, you are correct, your `Vector_push` and `Vector_pop` do operate as a stack, which matches their names. But the original code needed a queue (FIFO). :-)

Comment: @Ian Abbot, Then I'd add `Vector_shift`, and I'd add an `offset` field to the structure so that shift becomes O(1).

Comment: @ikegami Yes, the offset is a neat optimization. I hadn't thought of that!

Answer (score 0):

Allocation of temporary storage would be more efficient if you could get the number of elements in the tree efficiently, for example by maintaining a counter. Failing that, a recursive function could be used to count the elements:

```
size_t CountBSTElements(Node *root) {
    if (root)
        return 1 + CountBSTElements(root->left) + CountBSTElements(root->right);
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Once the total number of elements is known, the following function can be called to allocate an array filled with an in-order traversal of the tree:

```
/*
 * Allocates and fills array of node pointers from BST tree.
 * root is the root node and n is the total number of elements in the tree.
 */
Node **GetInOrderBSTNodes(Node *root, size_t n) {
    Node **nodes = malloc(n * sizeof(*nodes));
    size_t front = 0;
    size_t back = n;

    if (!nodes)
        return NULL;

    while (front < back) {
        if (root) {
            nodes[--back] = root;
            root = root->left;
        } else {
            root = nodes[back++];
            nodes[front++] = root;
            root = root->right;
        }
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

Demonstration follows. The temporary storage needs to be freed once it has been used to build the balanced tree.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};

/*
 * Allocates and fills array of node pointers from BST tree.
 * root is the root node and n is the total number of elements in the tree.
 */
Node **GetInOrderBSTNodes(Node *root, size_t n) {
    Node **nodes = malloc(n * sizeof(*nodes));
    size_t front = 0;
    size_t back = n;

    if (!nodes)
        return NULL;

    while (front < back) {
        if (root) {
            nodes[--back] = root;
            root = root->left;
        } else {
            root = nodes[back++];
            nodes[front++] = root;
            root = root->right;
        }
    }
    return nodes;
}

size_t CountBSTElements(Node *root) {
    if (root)
        return 1 + CountBSTElements(root->left) + CountBSTElements(root->right);
    else
        return 0;
}

/* 
 * N.B. The usage of the end index is slightly different in this version of
 * buildTreeUtil() compared to the linked source:
 * https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-normal-bst-balanced-bst/
 *
 * In this version, end is one past the last index.
 * I did it this way to keep the indices unsigned.
 */

/*
 * Build BST from array of node pointers.
 * nodes is the array of node pointers.
 * start is start index in the array.
 * end is one past the end index in the array.
 *
 * Sorry, it is recursive. :-)
 */
Node *BuildTreeUtil(Node **nodes, size_t start, size_t end)
{
    Node *root;
    size_t mid;

    if (start >= end)
        return NULL;

    mid = (start + end - 1) / 2;
    root = nodes[mid];
    root->left = BuildTreeUtil(nodes, start, mid);
    root->right = BuildTreeUtil(nodes, mid + 1, end);
    return root;
}

Node *BuildTree(Node *root, size_t nelems) {
    Node **nodes = GetInOrderBSTNodes(root, nelems);
 
    if (nodes) {
        /* Build BST from in-order node pointers. */
        root = BuildTreeUtil(nodes, 0, nelems);
        /* Free temporary storage. */
        free(nodes);
    } /* else leave it unbalanced */

    return root;
}

/* Utility function to create a new node */
/* Borrowed from linked source. */
Node *NewNode(int data) {
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));

    if (node) {
        node->data = data;
        node->left = NULL;
        node->right = NULL;
    }
    return (node);
}

/* Print in-order traversal of BST. */
/* Borrowed from linked source, but renamed. */
void PrintPreOrder(Node* node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return;
    printf("%d ", node->data);
    PrintPreOrder(node->left);
    PrintPreOrder(node->right);
}

int main(void) {
    Node *root;
    size_t count;

    /*
     * Construct unbalanced BST:
     *
     *         4
     *        / \ 
     *       3   5
     *      /     \ 
     *     2       6
     *    /         \ 
     *   1           7
     */
    root = NewNode(4);
    root->left = NewNode(3);
    root->left->left = NewNode(2);
    root->left->left->left = NewNode(1);
    root->right = NewNode(5);
    root->right->right = NewNode(6);
    root->right->right->right = NewNode(7);

    printf("Pre-order traversal of unbalanced BST is:\n");
    PrintPreOrder(root);
    printf("\n");

    /* Get number of nodes. */
#if 0
    count = 7;  /* efficient :-) */
#else
    count = CountBSTElements(root);
#endif

    /*
     * Build balanced BST:
     *
     *         4
     *       /   \ 
     *      2     6
     *     / \   / \ 
     *    1   3 5   7
     */
    root = BuildTree(root, count);

    printf("Pre-order traversal of balanced BST is:\n");
    PrintPreOrder(root);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```